# Incompatibilidade de CSS com jquery blockUI no IE 8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, jquery-blockui

Estou usando [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) *1.11.0* junto com o plugin [jquery-blockui](/questions/tagged/jquery-blockui) *2.66.0* e ao bloquear a tela, a *div* fica com fundo branco nos IE 8 e anteriores.

Seguem as imagens:

[image: Essa é a minha tela no IE-9, comportamento correto]
  [image: E essa no IE-8, com erro]

**A chamada para o blockUI:**

```
$.blockUI({
    message: "<p style=\"font-weight: bolder; color: white;\">N&atilde;o houve resultado para o seu filtro.<br /><br /><a class=\"fecharBlockUI\">Fechar</a></p>",
    timeout: 5000,
    onOverlayClick: $.unblockUI
});
```

Sei que devo fazer um CSS hack, mas não conheço bem front-end, alguém poderia me explicar como fazer para manter o comportamente igual à primeira imagem também no IE 8 e anteriores?

Como requisitado, segue a alteração de estilo do css:

```
$.blockUI.defaults.css = {
    border: "none",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)",
    textAlign: "center",
    padding: 0,
    margin: 0,
    width: "30%",
    top: "40%",
    left: "35%",
    color: "#000000",
    cursor: "wait" 
};
```

Comment: Usando seu código na [página de exemplo do plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) o fundo fica branco. Você deve estar substituindo o estilo padrão no CSS e por algum motivo isso não funciona no IE8. Poderia editar mostrando esses estilos?

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues Pelo que entendi o usuário quer o comportamento da primeira imagem e não da segunda o que implica realmente em mudar um pouco o CSS.

Comment: exatamente, quero o comportamento da primeira imagem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)",
```

Cores escritas como RGBA [não são suportadas no IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rgba). Use isso:

```
 backgroundColor: "transparent",
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente @GustavoRodrigues! Muito Obrigado cara!